# keep the first part of the URL and mask everything else

Tags: regex

How do I keep the first (domain) part of the URL and mask everything else after that?

This does not work:

```
s= ' Get exciting offers when you book a XX year car   June XX - XXXX Click here to book http://abc.in/XXzOK '

import re
formatting = [
    [r"http://abc.in/", "http://abc.in/XXXX"]
]

for regex,substitution in formatting:
    s = re.sub(regex, substitution, s)
    print (s)
```

The domain name can be anything like google.com or yahoo.com

Expected result:

```
Get exciting offers when you book a XX year car   June XX - XXXX Click here to book http://abc.in/XXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s = ' Get exciting offers when you book a XX year car   June XX - XXXX Click here to book http://abc.in/XXzOK '
s = re.sub(r'(https?://[^/]+/)\S*', r'\1XXXX', s)
print(s)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##JU09C8IwFNz9Fbel9aNB3ARxcBB0cHAJWIW2vNpQTcpLitY/H1Md3t1x3N3rBt9YswpBPzvLHkwThw0E9uRB70p7be6wdU3s8GrIYLA9SmtbFFAKAxWMKh5w6A2N1iJCpN1DVy0aYoK3/0bjfbeWsiirTBup1Od0hPj9Y8pcXyYskjHjtjF1ucnrTKb5eSrmYJEvx9UoXTrpWBufuDSELw)

**Regex:**

```py
(https?://[^/]+/)\S*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/KVwzVX/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `http` | 'http' |
| `s?` | 's' (optional (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `://` | '://' |
| `[^/]+` | any character except: '/' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | '/' |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\S*` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 2):

For the example, You could put `\S*` after the regex as you can see in [this demo](https://ideone.com/Bjl8pR) but then you would have to list all of the replacements.

One option for more urls could be using 2 groups, and could the number of characters in the second group replacing those by `X`

Or just replace the match after group 1 with `XXXX` without using group 2 in the pattern if it should be a fixed string in the replacement.

```
import re

s= ' Get exciting offers when you book a XX year car   June XX - XXXX Click here to book http://abc.in/XXzOK '    
s = re.sub(r"(https?://[^/\s]+/)(\S+)", lambda x: x.group(1) + 'X' * len(x.group(2)), s)

print(s)
```

Output

```
 Get exciting offers when you book a XX year car   June XX - XXXX Click here to book http://abc.in/XXXXX
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/35B2zI)